# loop through session looking for specific value

Tags: laravel

I save a session value like this

> Session::put('image.hash.'.$imageHash, $imageHash);

later I want to check on all sessions that are image.hash.* since I don't know at later time the value of $imageHash

I tried this

> if(Session::has('image.hash.*'))

but ofcourse it does not work. How can I loop through all these session values if I dont know the last part

> image.hash.djn6ago
>
> image.hash.fJtbru
>
> image.hash.ai12de

I also tried this

```
$session = Session::all();

forearch ($session as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, 'image.hash') !== false)  {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

but when I run that code I got this

> strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Edit:

Managed to loop through all keys of interest but have now another problem.

I did

> dd($session);

to find out what keys and values are there in session and found out that my image keys point to array instead of string like I expected, here is how they look

```
  "image-uploads/2016/11/25/15/twest-test" => array:1 [▼
    "jpg" => "uploads/2016/11/25/15/twest-test.jpg"
  ]
  "image-uploads/2016/11/25/15/moviefone" => array:1 [▼
    "png" => "uploads/2016/11/25/15/moviefone.png"
  ]
```

this is how I created them

> Session::put('image-'.$folder .'/'. $name, $folder .'/'. $name);

I now have problem to access the value information since it's in an array and this array key seems to be jpg, png, gif, bmp, etc depending on image that was uploaded. I do not understand how this key is added since I am not adding an array to the session key but an string.

Any ideas?

Comment: add `var_dump($value);` bevor your if to see whats in $value ;)

Comment: updated my question, need additional help, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

I think your $value contain array. Please debug or echo gettype($value) inside the foreach and see the output.

```
$session = Session::all();
    forearch ($session as $value) {
        echo gettype($value)
        if (strpos($value, 'image.hash') !== false)  {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are right, I have solved it like this $session as $key => $value and doing strpos on key instead of value, now it works

Comment: updated my question, need additional help, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

**For Edited Question:** Please debug as dd($value) in the foreach loop. Once the loop is execute then it will show one times output of $value then share the output here. Thanks.

```
$session = Session::all();
    forearch ($session as $value) {
        echo dd($value)
        if (strpos($value, 'image.hash') !== false)  {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
```